# logwatch with systemd/journald

Tags: logwatch

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
logwatch 7.5.2-1ubuntu1

I have following config for logwatch:

`/etc/logwatch/conf/logwatch.conf`

```
Output = mail
Detail = high
MailFrom = logwatch
Range = yesterday
Service = All
```

`/etc/logwatch/conf/logfiles/null.conf`

```
LogFile = /dev/null
```

`/etc/logwatch/conf/services/sshd.conf`

```
LogFile =
Logfile = null
*JournalCtl = "--output=cat --unit=ssh.service"
```

I am receiving the logwatch email, but it does not contain any ssh info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through some old support email in logwatch sourceforge site and some testing, following settings works:

`/etc/logwatch/conf/logfiles/null.conf`

```
LogFile = null.log
```

Create `/var/log/null.log` with an empty line.

Then logwatch work correctly for ssh.service.

Answer (score 0):

No need to muck with logfiles/*.conf, in `/etc/logwatch/conf/services/sshd.conf`:

```
Logfile =
Logfile = none
*JournalCtl = "--output=cat --unit=ssh.service"
```

Need to clear Logfile, then set to magic `none` value.